# How to extract specific post

Tags: wp-query, sql, meta-value

I've to extract only the posts where the meta_value does't contain some specific string.
I use this code:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
        array(  
            'post_type' => 'estate',
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'meta_key' => 'getrix_id',
            'meta_value' => array('miogest_', 'oneclick_', 'gestifiaip_'),
            'meta_compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    );
    var_dump($query);
```

I have to discard all the records with meta_value containing strings 'miogest_', 'gestifiaip_' and 'oneclick_' but, in this way, the returned results aren't correct.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) `meta_value`, when not used inside a meta query, needs to be a string.

Normally if you want to query based on multiple meta values you need to add a `meta_query` argument. But also as noted in the documentation regarding `value`:

> It can be an array only when `compare` is `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`,
>   `'BETWEEN'`, or `'NOT BETWEEN'`.

Since `NOT LIKE` isn't one of these, this means you would need to add multiple `NOT LIKE` meta queries with an `AND` relation, like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(  
    'post_type'   => 'estate',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'getrix_id',
            'value'   => 'miogest_',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'getrix_id',
            'value'   => 'oneclick_',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'getrix_id',
            'value'   => 'gestifiaip_',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
    ),  
) );
```

However this is pretty verbose. A simpler way would be to use `NOT REGEXP` as the comparison. This will let you pass a [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html) that would return true for any values beginning with `miogest_`, `oneclick_`, or `gestifiaip_`, and then only return results for which that *doesn't* return true:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'    => 'estate',
    'post_status'  => 'any',
    'meta_key'     => 'getrix_id'
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT REGEXP',
    'meta_value'   => '^(miogest_|oneclick_|gestifiaip_)',
) );
```